# How to pass password inline initdb postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I am using postgres 9.3 . I want to make a script to create my database cluster and supply the password inline in the terminal. I know you can do it from file, but is there a way to do it command line?

that is the line I am using right now : 'initdb -D path/to/cluster -W -A password'

it then prompt me for password, I tried to provide it inline, but it does not work. Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.3 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible. And you shouldn't use it for new projects

Comment: You could simply put the password into a file `echo secretpassword> password.txt` then use `initdb --pwfile=password.txt`

Comment: I created the file with: "echo secretpassword> password.txt" and then I created my cluster with: "initdb -D /path/to/dbCluster -A password --pwfile=/path/to/password.txt" . When I try to connect with  "psql -U dbuser -d postgres -p5555" it says:  FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "dbuser" ...Any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my initial question was to supply the password inline in the terminal. But ,the proper way of doing is using the password file for security reason. Second, in the initdb statement use at least md5 for encryption. The password will be for the superuser for the default database. You statement should look like this:

```
"initdb -D /path/to/dbCluster -A md5 --pwfile=/path/to/password.txt"
```

Now, if you want to automatically connect to the database with psql without password prompt, you have to create a .pgpass file (linux) or pgpass.conf file (windows) with your user and password info in this format: `host:port:db_name:user_name:password`

Where you put those file is important:

Windows :  `/Users/user_name/AppData/Roaming/postgresql/pgpass.conf`

(If the postgresql folder does not exist, you have to create it)

Linux : `/home/user/.pgpass` (with chmod 0600 permission on the file)

[How to force psql to detect .pgpass file on Windows 10 system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67708115/how-to-force-psql-to-detect-pgpass-file-on-windows-10-system)

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with a shell trick.  Assuming bash shell:

```
initdb -D path/to/cluster -A password --pwfile=<(echo secretpassword)
```

(Although you should never use `-A password`, use at least md5.)

As for your comment, it is hard to say what is going on.  You don't show us starting the server at all, or setting the port to start on to 5555, nor creating a user named 'dbuser'.

Comment: Here are each steps: 1- created the file with: "echo secretpassword> password.txt" , 2- created my cluster with: "initdb -D /path/to/dbCluster -A md5 --pwfile=/path/to/password.txt", 3 - started my server on port 5555 with : pg_ctl -D path/to/dbCluster -o -p5555 start and then 4 - connect to it: "psql -U dbuser -d postgres -p5555" it prompt me for password. I enter the password and it fail : FATAL: password authentication failed for user "dbuser"

Comment: The password you set in initdb is probably for a user other than 'dbuser'.  It should be for the user with the same spelling as the OS user you were logged in as when running initdb.

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone!

It worked when I changed 'password' to 'md5' in my initdb statement.

although in the password.txt file, I can only store the password. If I follow the documentation from postgres
host:port:username:password it does not work anymore

Comment: Those are two different things.  One is for setting the init superuser password during initdb, one (.pgpass) is for fetching the password to use for connecting to an existing running system.

Comment: I was able to create the init superuser password with: "initdb -D path/to/cluster -A md5 --pwfile=/path/to/file". But to do the same to connect....I was not able to replicate yet: I tried "psql -U username -d database passfile=/path/to/file", but it failed. Instead, It prompt me for password instead of connecting

Comment: Your psql command gives me "psql: warning: extra command-line argument "passfile=/path/to/file" ignored"

Comment: passfile did not work for me. instead I used .pgpass in /home folder. : "psql -U user -d database". If your .pgpass file is there it will pick up the password in that file. Formating the file like this host:port:username:password

Answer (score 0):

I solved the connection problem with .pgpass. I've created the .pgpass file in the home directory and I was able to connect using: "psql -U username -d database -pXXXX"