# How to force psql to detect .pgpass file on Windows 10 system?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, psql

I am working on Windows 10 system, python 3.9.4 in, anaconda env.
I have a `.pgpass` file: `localhost:port:db_name:user_name:password`

When I run:

```
psql -U user_name -d db_name -pXXXX
```

OR

```
psql -U user_name -d db_name -pXXXX -f /path/to/sql/file.sql
```

it prompts me for a password. When I enter the password I can connect, but I would like psql to pick up the pgpass file instead.

My theory is: The format of the pgpass. Does it require specific EOL characters on Windows system?

```
localhost:port:db_name_1:user_name_1:password_1 <CR or LF>
localhost:port:db_name_2:user_name_2:password_2 <CR or LF>
```

Comment: Also, when I try "psql -U user_name -d db_name -pXXXX -w" I get the following output: psql: error: could not connect to server: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Comment: The line ending doesn't matter. I guess the file might not be in the correct place. What does `type %AppData%\postgresql\pgpass.conf` give you? Or do you maybe have the environment variable ` PGPASSFILE` defined which points to a non-standard location?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html

Comment: My postgres is installed in a conda environment. Where should my pgpass.conf be placed then?

Comment: Where should my pgpass.conf be placed then? C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\ENV_NAME\???  Is there a command to return where psql is looking for pgpass.conf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make it work. I had to create the 'postgresql' folder. It was not there. Afterwards, I added the 'pgpass.conf' file and I was able to login without password prompt from my conda environment.

```
/Users/user_name/AppData/Roaming/postgresql/pgpass.conf
```

thanks everyone for your help.